# .htaccess redirect of index.php is breaking 404 pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have recently setup a index.php redirect through .htaccess. The idea here is to negate duplicate content issue that crops up when a site has both an index.php and / (homapage) getting indexed.

Here is my original .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /customerrors/403.html
ErrorDocument 401 /customerrors/401.html
ErrorDocument 400 /customerrors/400.html
ErrorDocument 500 /customerrors/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/404.html
```

Pretty basic.

I used the technique listed here to redirect the index.php to /.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/redirect-index-blog-root.html

It works great too. One issue is, it breaks the 404 pages.

This is the modified .htaccess that is breaking the 404 pages.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /customerrors/403.html
ErrorDocument 401 /customerrors/401.html
ErrorDocument 400 /customerrors/400.html
ErrorDocument 500 /customerrors/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /customerrors/404.html
```

So if a user types in or goes to www.example.com/dafjkadbfda instead of serving 404 page, the URL remains the same(in this case the broken one) and severs the index.php page.

This in turn is opening another can of worms. All those broken pages are coming up as duplicate content and meta.

Is there another way to write the .htacess redirect that will take into account the 404 pages? Seems like that is the conflict here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was able to get this solved.  [.htaccess index redirect with custom 404s](http://pastebin.com/LUJmMVrN)

Answer (score 0):

This part of the .htaccess is the one that "breaks" the 404:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You could manage the problem by sending a 404 error from your PHP script:

```
if ($not_a_valid_page){
    header("$_SERVER[SERVER_PROTOCOL] 404 Not Found");
    readfile("./customerrors/404.html");
    die();
}
```